# Microsoft Custom Translator - Undeployment of the Model After System Maitenance

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

After the maintenance of the MS Custom Translator main page on Nov 14-15, a few of our models were undeployed (though a really small fraction). API was working well during this period and surprisingly even after the 'undeployment' - we are not sure if the model fell back to some generic mode or just UI was wrong and the models were still deployed. (We fixed the issue with redeployment.)

Didn't receive any API error or email notif.

Does anybody have the same experience or are those just unrelated events?

Comment: can you confirm Is the custom translations working as expected?

Comment: haven't noticed any issues, just UI ones as described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no API error. Deployed models were not affected during the Custom Translator maintenance period. This information was indicated in the Custom Translator portal.

An email was sent from the Custom Translator email alias. Check junk folder. It would have been sent to those individuals who are listed in the portal who have access to their custom models. Please let us know if not and send us the email address.

Comment: I noticed the outrage information. Haven't received any message, though at least two workspaces were affected. But the effect was very limited

Comment: we would recommend to raise a Azure support desk ticket from Help+Support blade from Azure portal for your resource if you have a support plan for your subscription.